# Can't remove child object

Tags: nhibernate, collections, parent-child, one-to-many

I have the problem with removing object from the child collection.
I have a parent class with child objects collection.

```
public class Document
{
    public Document()
    {
        Pages = new List<DocumentPage>();
    }

    public virtual Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<DocumentPage> Pages { get; set; }
}
public class DocumentPage
{
public virtual Int64 Id { get; set; }
public virtual Document Document { get; set; }
}
```

The following are the mappers …

```
  <class name="Document">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>

    <bag name="Pages" table="DocumentPage" inverse="true" lazy="true" 
         fetch="select"  cascade="all-delete-orphan">
      <key>
        <column name="DocumentId" not-null="true" />
      </key>
      <one-to-many class="DocumentPage" />
    </bag>

  </class>

  <class name="DocumentPage">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="Document" class="Document" fetch="select">
      <column name="DocumentId" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
  </class>
```

I have to delete the child object. In order to do this I remove it from the child objects collection and save the parent object.

The problem is that I can’t remove the page from the pages collection.
**`document.Pages.Remove(page)` returns false** and the collection remains unchanged.

I suppose that happens because of proxy class (`DocumentPageProxy`).
Some extra check shows that:

```
page.Equals(document.Pages[0]) returns **false** when
Equals(page, document.Pages[0]) returns **true**.
document.Pages.RemoveAt(0) works fine.
```

I have no idea what is wrong here and how should I remove/delete child object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override Equals and GetHashCode in order for Remove to be able to find the DocumentPage based on its identifier value instead of reference equality. Alternatively you could do:

```
var pageToRemove = document.Pages.Single(p => p.ID == page.Id);
document.Pages.Remove(pageToRemove);
```